# SVN Subdirectory is still in branch but root is trunk

Tags: svn, version-control

I have checked out branch `V1.2.3_hotfix-1`. I wanted to checkout HEAD trunk version. But it did not work. I have the following structure now.

- SVN Root has URL `svn://server/myportal/trunk`
- SVN Root/api has following URL `svn://server/myportal/branches/V1.2.3_hotfix-1/api`.

How can i fix this?

```
glsdev@glsonedev:~/dev/myportal$ svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /home/glsdev/dev/myportal
URL: svn://server/myportal/trunk
Relative URL: ^/trunk
Repository Root: svn://server/myportal
Repository UUID: 28da928d-5215-0510-adb9-eb8ce30c5931
Revision: 3120
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: joar27697844
Last Changed Rev: 3120
Last Changed Date: 2017-03-14 11:30:37 +0100 (Di, 14 Mär 2017)

glsdev@glsonedev:~/dev/myportal$ cd api 
glsdev@glsonedev:~/dev/myportal/api$ svn info
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /home/glsdev/dev/myportal
URL: svn://server/myportal/branches/V1.2.3_hotfix-1/api
Relative URL: ^/branches/V1.2.3_hotfix-1/api
Repository Root: svn://server/myportal
Repository UUID: 28da928d-5215-0510-adb9-eb8ce30c5931
Revision: 3120
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: mijo27698561
Last Changed Rev: 2978
Last Changed Date: 2017-02-22 14:35:38 +0100 (Mi, 22 Feb 2017)
```

I tried http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html as well but it didnot work. svn clean revert all didnot work as well.

Comment: Please can you indicate us the commands you ran to obtain this working copy ?

Comment: I checked out this branch V1.2.3_hotfix-1 in intellij by using SVN->Update Director y to branch. Everything was ok. Once I try to switch to HEAD trunk I got this structure. I used intellij SVN->update directory->to trunk.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, how this issue came about is likely specific to exactly how Intellij translated your menu commands to svn commands.  I will not speculate here.

You should be able to switch just the api directory back to trunk using following command (run inside `~/dev/myportal` based on your description):

```
svn switch ^/trunk/api api
```

This is assuming the `api` directory exists in trunk.  If it does not, you'll need to copy it into the trunk first:

```
svn copy ^/branches/V1.2.3_hotfix-1/api ^/trunk
```